# Android extended Timer

Tags: android, timer, runnable

I want to know that can we create a single timer to handle two different background calls in different durations ? I have a code which updates the local time in my application in 30 seconds. What i want is to, not create any other timer but in the same timer, call a different function after 60 seconds. Here is my code

```
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 10000,30000);

        class RemindTask extends TimerTask 
        {
            public void run()
                    {

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                       {
                             public void run() 
                             {
                                printMessage();// Current time
                             }
                       });
                    }
        }
```

Comment: Simple answer is no, as you have already set it's time if you change it, it will work as new changed interval

Comment: @Raynold so i have to create a new timer ? How much it will be efficient to create a new timer with respect to memory and battery consumption ? thanks

Comment: @CodeAddiction : what problem u are facing in current logic

Comment: @CodeAddiction Yes, you have to create another one, of course it will going to consume extra part of memory and battery depending on the code you have written.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, the problem is, the time is updated after every 60 seconds but i am updating it after every 30 seconds that is one thing, but what happens is, i am getting the weather update as well from yahoo api and they update their data almost after 1 hour so i want to have a timer which gets the data after an hour saving unnecessary hits on the api ? what will be better ? another timer or hit the api after 30 seconds ? thanks

Comment: Since 60 is multiple of 30, you could create a boolean and keep if you should run both update functions, or only one.     Or you could have a counter to 120 (2 * 60 minutes) to call the weather update only after one hour.

Comment: @AdrianC., thanks, seems better to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be:

```
class RemindTask extends TimerTask 
    {
        public void run()
                {

                   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                   {
                         public void run() 
                         {
                            count++;
                            if(count%120 == 0)
                                 weatherApiCall();

                            printMessage();// Current time
                         }
                   });
                }
    }
```

Where count is a variable that allows you to know how many times the TimerTask was runned and to call the weatherApiCall one an hour.

Comment: Great! will definitely give a try in few hours :)